# Superharmonic function and super martingale.

Tags: probability-theory

The definition (from Durrett's "Probability: Theory and Examples"):

> Superharmonic functions. The name (super martingale)
>   comes from the fact that if $f$ is superharmonic (i.e., f has continuous derivatives of
>   order $\le 2$ and $\partial^2 f /\partial^2 x_1^2 + · · · + \partial^2 f /\partial^2 x_d^2)$, then
>   $$
> f (x) \ge \frac 1 {|B(0, r)|} \int_{B(x,r)} f(y) dy
> $$
>   where $B(x, r) = \{y : |x − y| \le r\}$ is the ball of radius $r$, and $|B(0, r)|$ is the volume of the ball of radius $r$.

The question is

> Suppose $f$ is superharmonic on $R^d$. Let $\xi_1 , \xi_2 , ...$ be i.i.d. uniform
>   on $B(0, 1)$, and define $S_n$ by $S_n = S_{n−1} + \xi_n$ for $n \ge 1$ and $S_0 = x$. Show that $X_n = f (S_n)$ is a supermartingale.

Here the filtration should be $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma \{X_n, X_{n-1}...\}$.

I know to prove $X_n, n \ge 0$ is a super martingale, we only need to show
$$
E\{X_{n+1} ~|~ \mathcal{F}_n\} \leq X_n.
$$
This is easy when $n=0$. But for $n > 0$, I've no idea how to, or if it is possible, to derive the formula of the conditional expectation.

Comment: This is a straightforward consequence of two basic properties of conditional expectation, often summarized by "integrate that which is independent and keep that which is measurable". What are your sources on conditional expectation?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I missed something very basic when I studied conditional expectation. I'm reading this book : http://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/pte.html

Comment: Here is a copy of that book http://www.lce.esalq.usp.br/arquivos/aulas/2011/LCE5866/Probability-Theory%20and%20Examples.pdf

Comment: Hi, I guess by "integrate that which is independent and keep that which is measurable", you mean something like $E(X + Y|\mathcal{F})=E(X) + Y$ is $X$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}$ and $Y$ is measurable w.r.p. to $\mathcal{F}$. Is that right?

Comment: More something like $E(u(X,Y)\mid\mathcal F)=v(Y)$ where $v(y)=E(u(X,y))$.

Comment: I got it thanks!

Answer (score 4):

$f(S_{n+1})=f(S_n+\xi_{n+1})$

Using Did's Hint: If $g(x)=E(f(x,Y))$ then $g(X)=E(f(X,Y)|X)$

$\Rightarrow E(f(S_n+\xi_{n+1})|\mathcal F_n)=g(S_n)$

but $\displaystyle g(x)=\int f(x+y)\nu(dy)$

and in our case $\nu(dy)=\mathbf 1_{B(0,1)}\frac{1}{|B(0,1)|}dy$ (because $\xi_i$ are uniform on $B(0,1)$)

$\displaystyle\Rightarrow g(S_n)=\int  f(S_n+y)\mathbf 1_{B(0,1)}\frac{1}{|B(0,1)|}dy=\frac{1}{|B(0,1)|}\int_{B(S_n,1)}f(y)dy\le f(S_n)$